# Make subquery usage more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following example query:

```
SELECT Name, Number,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Street FROM tableA b WHERE a.Name = b.Name AND a.Number = b.Number AND b.Type = 'VILLA' AND b.Value IN (5, 1, 9)) x) as NumberOfStreetsForVillas,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Street FROM tableA b WHERE a.Name = b.Name AND a.Number = b.Number AND b.Type = 'SMALL' AND b.Value IN (1, 2, 3)) x) as NumberOfStreetsForSmallHouses,
FROM dbo.tableA a
GROUP BY Name, Number
```

How can I make this query more efficient?

I have read about using a SELECT COUNT(1) + subselect (which I did) instead of using a COUNT(DISTINCT), but is there a way to turn this into a more efficient query using joins?

This is just an example query, so the actually query will probably contain about 12 subqueries instead of 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use Cross Apply: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT...)`?, why not just `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`?

Comment: Well, if I would use 1 cross apply (without tableB.Type and tableB.Value condition), how can I apply those conditions to count the amount of rows for NumberOfStreetsForVillas and ForSmallHouses?

Comment: @Lamak I read [here](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.periscope.io%2Fblog%2Fuse-subqueries-to-count-distinct-50x-faster.html&ei=QohLVemOGMiUsAHSxYHwBA&usg=AFQjCNFBwpcF4mqWBOMn2yRh0twRKoeCLg&sig2=CpEW-zRREIm4BgXfd7OwaA&bvm=bv.92765956,d.ZGU) that it's better to use subqueries than COUNT(DISTINCT..)

Comment: @JonathanDeBadrihaye That post is about Postgres. Read the continuation: https://www.periscope.io/blog/count-distinct-in-mysql-postgres-sql-server-and-oracle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should do the same thing. It's a little difficult to know for sure since I don't know what your data looks like, but even so... This should work:

```
SELECT
    a.Name, 
    a.Number, 
    Count(Distinct CASE WHEN b.type='Villa' AND b.value in (5,1,9) THEN b.street END) as NumberOfStreetsForVillas
    Count(Distinct CASE WHEN b.type='Small' AND b.value in (1,2,3) THEN b.Street END) as NumberOfCitiesForSmallHouses
FROM dbo.tableA a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tableb b
        ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Number = b.Number
GROUP BY a.Name, a.Number;
```

Comment: It's debatable whether this would be faster than joining to a subquery of tableb twice and then grouping by everything. In the subqueries you would do the filtering and counting, which is pretty much what you are doing in the `SELECT`, but properly down in the `FROM`. I think you'll find the performance acceptable for the query I've written though.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to get very slow as I use more COUNT(DISTINCT) in one view. Is there a way to do this with a subquery? I also just noticed that tableB is actually also tableA, although the only difference would be: no more join but still a count distinct that makes the query slow.

Comment: An index on `(Name, Number, Type, Value) INCLUDE (Street)` would probably improve the  efficiency of the query.